# UITextView inside ScrollView causing unwanted behaviour

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit

I am using a UITextView wrapper to display **multiline** text inside a ScrollView that can be long pressed to select. If I do not use a ScrollView, everything works correctly (text selection, wrapping over the line) as shown in the test program below.

However, when I try to use the wrapper inside a ScrollView, some problems happen.

By default, nothing is displayed. After searching, I thought that this is due to the original UITextView also being scrollable, so I disabled the scrolling using `textView.isScrollEnabled = false.`

Now the text is rendering, but the width is really wide and most of it cannot be seen. If I rotate the simulator phone to landscape mode, the text can fully fit, but I am not sure if it is meant to render to exactly landscape width.

I have tried to force change the width of the view, but nothing happens.

Any help is appreciated.

```swift
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

struct TextViewWrapper: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var text: String

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextView {
        let textView = UITextView()
        textView.isEditable = false
        textView.isSelectable = true
//        textView.isScrollEnabled = false
        textView.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .body)
        textView.delegate = context.coordinator
        return textView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ textView: UITextView, context: Context) {
        textView.text = text
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextViewDelegate {
        var parent: TextViewWrapper

        init(_ parent: TextViewWrapper) {
            self.parent = parent
        }

        func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
            parent.text = textView.text
        }
    }
}


struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var s1: String = """
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed convallis mauris mauris, viverra pharetra tellus bibendum sed. Sed sit amet ultricies mi. Vestibulum tempor elit libero, in cursus sem rutrum nec. Vivamus sodales dui sapien, quis posuere turpis cursus at. Ut vestibulum est lorem, eget placerat nulla varius et. Phasellus ac erat at eros pretium blandit. Etiam maximus sagittis orci, eget pretium ante finibus id. Aliquam convallis augue nec elit eleifend luctus. Pellentesque sollicitudin sapien mauris, scelerisque dictum libero condimentum vitae.
"""
    
    @State private var s2: String = """
Cras at nisi in dui luctus dapibus porttitor semper nulla. Suspendisse vitae ante sit amet risus tempus pharetra. Integer consectetur quam in condimentum lobortis. Integer egestas magna in vestibulum facilisis. Duis ipsum elit, porttitor nec lectus sit amet, lacinia euismod neque. Aenean ac diam nec turpis fermentum rhoncus quis eget odio. Proin bibendum purus ligula, in pharetra mi hendrerit quis. Sed congue maximus turpis, et lacinia neque pellentesque sit amet. Aenean sit amet arcu a elit auctor maximus. Donec erat libero, maximus eget luctus eget, congue vitae libero. Nullam et feugiat tortor, venenatis auctor mi. Nullam id interdum turpis.
"""
    var body: some View {
//        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                TextViewWrapper(text: $s1)
                TextViewWrapper(text: $s2)
            }
            .padding()
//        }
    }
}


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```